# migrate from Adobe Flex SDK 4.6 with AIR SDK 3.9 to Apache Flex SDK 4.12.0 with AIR SDK 3.9

Tags: apache-flex, air

I developed an application with Adobe Flex SDK 4.6 and Air SDK 3.9. Now I want to ship it to Apache Flex SDK 4.12.0 with AIR SDK 3.9 for use with Adobe Flash Builder.

I followed the steps list at the following links

1. http://flex.apache.org/installer.html
2. http://apache-flex-users.2333346.n4.nabble.com/Apache-Flex-4-12-release-candidate-td4888.html
3. http://lucamezzalira.com/2012/07/24/how-to-install-flex-4-8-0-sdk-in-flash-builder/

After I set the new configuration of the Flex SDK I get the following errors:

> flex2.compiler.as3.EmbedEvaluator.UnableToTranscode 
>   flex2.compiler.media.AbstractTranscoder.UnableToGenerateSource

Can someone help me migrate from Adobe Flex SDK to Apache Flex SDK 4.12.0 ?

Comment: Are you using extended characters in your code? Also - did you do a 'clean' before rebuilding with the new SDK?

Comment: I don't understand mean by "extended characters". I clean and rebuild the application still it showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved when restart the Flash builder